# Does write concern helps to achieve synchronous replication in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If we select any value for w option will it first apply changes to primary then on others ? and can we consider it as synchronous replication ?

Answer (score 0):

W options- This is write concern.

It describes the level of acknowledgement requested from MongoDB for write operations to a standalone mongod or to replica sets or to sharded clusters.

Mongo Db is widely used installed on distributed machines with replicated data sets. In case mongo db is configured such as to ensure like whenever write operation is performed, acknowledgement will be given only when write is successfully applied to **all replica sets** then is such case it an be considered as synchronous replication. However,Higher the replication factor more will be the acknowledgement time and this will degrade the write performance.

If lower value like 1 is chosen, acknowledgement is given if write is successful for primary.Secondary members copy the oplog from their primary source and apply these operations in an asynchronous process.

Hope this helps.